# Documentation on setting width on <img> as an inline element

Tags: css, image, width

It used to be that images as an inline element would not accept a css styled width unless also styled as inline-block. Now some browsers appear to support a width on images. Is there some new W3C decision here or is it just a browser development decision or...?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and then [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.